# Unable to create the video output file of screen recording with PIL library

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

FOllowing is my code. I see this code working in a tutorial but does not seem to create the output video file for me. Can anyone suggest, what could be the issue here?

I expect an output video file in the execution root directory with the name as provided at

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab


fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 5.0, (800, 600))

while True:
    bild = ImageGrab.grab()
    img_np = np.array(bild)

    frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    cv2.imshow("Screen", frame)
    out.write(frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You have forgotten all the `import` statements. You seem to be assigning `out` twice for no apparent reason. You don't check for any errors when you call functions. You don't tell us if it displays anything. Kindly put those issues right and come back if it still doesn't work.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have corrected the code with import and deletion of duplicated items. I do not get any errors, the code work. It starts a screen recording instance which is visible on my screen (it duplicates whatever I am doing). At the press of "Esc" key as identified with value 27. It breaks that sequence but does not save the output file as I hope to get with videoWriter.

Comment: Try `bild = ImageGrab.grab().resize((800,600))` and/or `fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')`

Comment: @MarkSetchell . Doesn't work. Tried both in combinations.

Comment: Ok, run it in `ipython` or the debugger, one line at a time and check and print every function you call, every result you receive and the size and type of all your variables before you run the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the program as admin and/or setting the output file's write path to non-system directories fixes the issue.